# Baikal 0.4.5: synchronization with Thunderbird + Lightning + SOGo connector

Tags: synchronization, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon, sabredav, thunderbird-lightning

To upgrade Baikal from 0.2.7 to 0.4.5 I followed the steps on http://sabre.io/baikal/upgrade. The upgrade was successful. At the end of process I changed the end-points for syncing. Syncing calendars on all devices (PC + Thunderbird 45.0 + Lightning 4.7 + SOGo connector 31.0.3, iphone 5s (9.3.2)) works fine, but syncing contacts is a problem:

Before I started the upgrade I made an additional local copy of my baikal-remote-adress book in Thunderbird and deleted all contacts on the baikal server. After the upgrade I copied (and moved) my local contacts to the upgraded baikal-remote-adress book in Thunderbird. Only a few, but not all contacts are synchronized. I have checked this on my iphone as well as on the baikal-dashboard, where you can see the number of contacts in your adress book. In Thunderbird all contacts are advisiable.

The curiosty is the following:

- If I create a new contact in Thunderbird, this one is going to be synchronized immediatley.
- If I edit an non-synchronized contact in Thunderbird and save the changes, this one also is going to be synchronized immediatley.
- The other direction also works fine: creating a new contact on my iphone synchronizes Thunderbird´s view. Future editing this contact works fine in all directions.

I have tried copying (and moving) local contacts to a fresh installed baikal-remote-adress book in Thunderbird. The result is the same, only a few contacts are synchronized.
So, what goes wrong?